# Create MAPI profile for exchange 2007 without Outlook

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-2007

I have a windows server 2003 where I have to create a MAPI profile to read incoming emails of exchange 2007, using a custom utility. So I want the mail icon to appear in the control panel to configure e-mail accounts.

I googled a lot and seems that there was a way to do it with an utility called newprof.exe but it is no longer available:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306962

I don't have an outlook license so I need a free way to create MAPI profiles in this server, either installing a free client or some ms tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mail icon in the Control Panel is part of Outlook, so without Outlook, you'll have to use some alternate methods to get a profile created.  Here's something to try:

1) You have to have MAPI installed.  No way around that.  You can download it here: [Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Client and Collaboration Data Objects 1.2.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e17e7f31-079a-43a9-bff2-0a110307611e&displaylang=en).  There are some limitations such as not being able to work with Unicode PSTs.  If you're just looking to read new messages, you should be fine.

2) Use [MFCMAPI](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/) to create the profile.  Here's the steps:

- Download and run the exe.
- Choose the Profile menu item, Show Profiles
- Then Action, Create Profile.
- Give the profile a name.
- Right click on the new profile and choose Add Exchange Mailbox.
- Enter in the Exchange server (I recommend using the FQDN) and the mailbox's Display Name.  I haven't tested to see if it will resolve based on an email address.

That should get a basic profile created to be able to use without installing Outlook.